# How to define a Flat file schema for a record with a repeating sequence?

Tags: xsd, biztalk, flat-file

I have a positional flat file which contains records with a repeating sequence, like this;

```
TOKEN NAME LABEL VALUE LABEL VALUE LABEL VALUE LABEL VALUE ..
```

The TOKEN identifies the type of record, the name is a name value, and the LABEL (10 positions) and VALUE (50 positions) pairs can repeat a not-fixed number of times (1..*).

I have defined a flat file schema as below; It contains a  (1..*), with a LABEL and a VALUE with the correct positional data:

[image: repeating sequence schema]

Both LABEL and VALUE have a **minOccurs** and a **maxOccurs** of 1.

The problem I have is that BizTalk does not seam to be able to handle this situation. When I generate a (native) instance for this schema I get the following output:

```
TOKEN NAME        LABEL     VALUE
```

(It generates only a single instance of LABEL VALUE).

When I try to read a file that has multiple occurrences of LABEL VALUE pairs (5), it gives me the following XML:

```
<FILE xmlns="http://schemas.demo/2015/01">
    <RepeatingRecord xmlns="">
        <NAME>NAME</NAME>
        <LABEL>LABEL</LABEL>
        <LABEL>VALUE</LABEL>
        <LABEL>LABEL</LABEL>
        <LABEL>VALUE</LABEL>
        <LABEL>LABEL</LABEL>
        <LABEL>VALUE</LABEL>
        <LABEL>LABEL</LABEL>
        <LABEL>VALUE</LABEL>
        <LABEL>LABEL</LABEL>
        <LABEL>VALUE</LABEL>
    </RepeatingRecord>
</FILE>
```

So I only get LABEL tags, but no VALUE tags. The contents of the VALUE parts are placed wrongly in a LABEL tag.

I would expect the following XML:

```
<FILE xmlns="http://schemas.demo/2015/01">
    <RepeatingRecord xmlns="">
        <NAME>NAME</NAME>
        <LABEL>LABEL</LABEL>
        <VALUE>VALUE</VALUE>
        <LABEL>LABEL</LABEL>
        <VALUE>VALUE</VALUE>
        <LABEL>LABEL</LABEL>
        <VALUE>VALUE</VALUE>
        <LABEL>LABEL</LABEL>
        <VALUE>VALUE</VALUE>
        <LABEL>LABEL</LABEL>
        <VALUE>VALUE</VALUE>
    </RepeatingRecord>
</FILE>
```

**How can I define a flat file schema with a repeating sequence in the record?**

I currently have the following schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://schemas.goudse.nl/irma/adapter/2015/01" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="unqualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.goudse.nl/irma/adapter/2015/01" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo>
      <b:schemaInfo standard="Flat File" root_reference="FILE" default_pad_char="0x20" pad_char_type="hex" count_positions_by_byte="false" parser_optimization="speed" lookahead_depth="3" suppress_empty_nodes="true" generate_empty_nodes="false" allow_early_termination="true" early_terminate_optional_fields="false" allow_message_breakup_of_infix_root="false" compile_parse_tables="false" document_type="ASFBatchFlatFileSchema" version="2015.01" schema_type="document" default_child_order="postfix" child_delimiter_type="hex" default_child_delimiter="0x0D 0x0A" />
      <schemaEditorExtension:schemaInfo namespaceAlias="b" extensionClass="Microsoft.BizTalk.FlatFileExtension.FlatFileExtension" standardName="Flat File" xmlns:schemaEditorExtension="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/SchemaEditorExtensions" />
    </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:element name="FILE">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:appinfo>
        <b:recordInfo structure="delimited" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" sequence_number="1" child_order="default" notes="Een compleet bestand" />
      </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
            <b:groupInfo sequence_number="0" />
          </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="RepeatingRecord">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
              <b:recordInfo structure="positional" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" tag_name="TOKEN " notes="Data behorende bij de schadebrief" sequence_number="1" />
            </xs:appinfo>
          </xs:annotation>
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:annotation>
                <xs:appinfo>
                  <b:groupInfo sequence_number="0" />
                </xs:appinfo>
              </xs:annotation>
              <xs:element name="NAME" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="1" pos_length="12" pos_offset="6" pad_char_type="hex" pad_char="0x20" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:groupInfo sequence_number="2" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
                <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="LABEL" type="xs:string">
                  <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:appinfo>
                      <b:fieldInfo justification="left" pos_length="10" pad_char_type="hex" pad_char="0x20" sequence_number="1" />
                    </xs:appinfo>
                  </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="VALUE" type="xs:string">
                  <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:appinfo>
                      <b:fieldInfo justification="left" pos_length="50" pad_char_type="hex" pad_char="0x20" sequence_number="2" />
                    </xs:appinfo>
                  </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

and the following test data file (replaced spaces with periods for clarity, the schema defines spaces for padding).

```
TOKEN.NAME........LABEL.....VALUE.............................................LABEL.....VALUE.............................................LABEL.....VALUE.............................................LABEL.....VALUE.............................................LABEL.....VALUE.............................................
```

**UPDATE**

What I did not mention in this question (for sake of simplicity) is that this record is used in a flat file with multiple kinds of different records, so splitting this record into child-records is not a viable solution.

Comment: Have you already tried something in a schema? Can you post it? Thanks.

Comment: Could you post a relevant sample of your flat file?  It's hard to know what you need without info on all the structure/records in your file

Answer (score 2):

I was able to validate the input from the top of your post with the following, hopefully it gets you ont he right track:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://BizTalk_Server_Project2.FlatFileSchema2" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" targetNamespace="http://BizTalk_Server_Project2.FlatFileSchema2" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo>
      <schemaEditorExtension:schemaInfo namespaceAlias="b" extensionClass="Microsoft.BizTalk.FlatFileExtension.FlatFileExtension" standardName="Flat File" xmlns:schemaEditorExtension="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/SchemaEditorExtensions" />
      <b:schemaInfo standard="Flat File" codepage="65001" default_pad_char=" " pad_char_type="char" count_positions_by_byte="false" parser_optimization="speed" lookahead_depth="3" suppress_empty_nodes="false" generate_empty_nodes="true" allow_early_termination="false" early_terminate_optional_fields="false" allow_message_breakup_of_infix_root="false" compile_parse_tables="false" root_reference="FILE" />
    </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:element name="FILE">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:appinfo>
        <b:recordInfo structure="positional" sequence_number="1" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" />
      </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
            <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
          </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:element name="FILE_Child1" type="xs:string">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
              <b:fieldInfo justification="left" pos_offset="0" pos_length="6" sequence_number="1" />
            </xs:appinfo>
          </xs:annotation>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="FILE_Child2" type="xs:string">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
              <b:fieldInfo justification="left" pos_offset="0" pos_length="5" sequence_number="2" />
            </xs:appinfo>
          </xs:annotation>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="FILE_Child3">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
              <b:recordInfo structure="positional" sequence_number="3" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" />
            </xs:appinfo>
          </xs:annotation>
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:annotation>
                <xs:appinfo>
                  <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
                </xs:appinfo>
              </xs:annotation>
              <xs:element name="FILE_Child3_Child1" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" pos_offset="0" pos_length="6" sequence_number="1" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="FILE_Child3_Child2" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" pos_offset="0" pos_length="6" sequence_number="2" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Would you care to explain this solution?

Comment: It creates a repeating record for LABEL and VALUE within the TOKEN record.  You said this won't work because of other features of your document, but I don't know what I can do about that without seeing more of the document.